# Looking for the Deligne's example of a non trivial topos with no points

Tags: reference-request, topos-theory

In the [topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos#Counterexamples) entry of wikipedia, says:

there is an example due to Pierre Deligne of a nontrivial topos that has no points (see below for the definition of points of a topos).

I'm looking for the reference of this example.

Comment: Look for instance at example 7.12 iii) of P.T Johnston “Topos Theory”

Comment: Some examples were recently discussed in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306483/locales-as-spaces-of-ideal-imaginary-points/). Basically, there are lots of such toposes, for instance the topos of surjections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Its points are the surjections from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Because no such surjection exists, the topos doesn't have any point.